# The browser is using Arial even though AvenirLTStd is available

Tags: css

The browser is using Arial even though AvenirLTStd is available:

```
<font style="font-family: 'AvenirLTStd','Arial'; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.17; letter-spacing: 0.6px; width: 34px; height: 12px; object-fit: contain; text-align: left; color: #4b4b4b;">
  Random Text
</font>
```

Browser is rendering this text is in Arial but AvenirLTStd is available even on w3schools the text is in Arial but when i removed the Arial from the font-family then the text is showing in AvenirLTStd.

Comment: In which language or technology you are trying to apply? in html or any js framework or library?

Comment: I am using SAP hybris technology, I am doing styling in .vm file. But even when i try to use this styling in W3schools i faced the same issue

Comment: have you attached Avenir LT Std Font locally or google font?

Comment: Loading local fonts is unreliable. You may add a `@font-face` rule with a `src: local(local("AvenirLTStd-Light"))` . This may work in some browser (works in chrome - not in firefox). I'm also not sure if the old `<font>` element is still widely supported. All in all you should prefer to load fonts locally via font-face